# Pagekey becomes null in OnNavigatedFrom in layoutawarepage

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime

I am developing a windows 8 app and I have the following page, a contact picker page where i have a submit button with the following code

```
 customContact = (CustomContacts)contactView.SelectedItem;   
 this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(AddTask), customContact);
```

my AddTask page has the follwoing method

```
 protected  override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    { if (e.Parameter == null)
        {code logic }}
```

now I m getting an error in layout aware page during button click as PageKey is null in its onnavigatedfrom event as such

```
  protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {                    
        var frameState = SuspensionManager.SessionStateForFrame(this.Frame);
        var pageState = new Dictionary<String, Object>();
        this.SaveState(pageState);          
        frameState[_pageKey] = pageState;
    }
```

Pls help me out

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`_pageKey` value is being set in `LayoutAwarePage.OnNavigatedTo`. Since you have overriden `OnNavigatedTo` in you own page without calling the base implementation, the code in `LayoutAwarePage` setting `_pageKey` never gets called.

When overriding a method you should always call its base implementation unless you know very well why you're not doing it. Adding the call to `base.OnNavigatedTo(e)` should fix your problem:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{ 
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    if (e.Parameter == null)
    {
        // code logic 
    }
}
```